# Python: Use Sister Parameters in Constructing Default Values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know I can do this in scala, but is there a way to do something similar in python:

```
def validate_config(data_dir, config_file_dir = data_dir + '/config', json_schema = None):
    print(data_dir)
    print(config_file_dir)
    print(json_schema)

validate_config('data')
```

The output I'm expecting is:

```
data
data/config
None
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not directly supported. I would do this the same way Python avoids mutable default instances:

```
def validate_config(data_dir, config_file_dir=None, json_schema=None):
    if config_file_dir is None:
        config_file_dir = data_dir + '/config'
    # rest of code here
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, because Python's default args are evaluated when the function definition is compiled. But you can use `None` as the default arg and check it at run-time, like this:

```
def validate_config(data_dir, config_file_dir=None, json_schema=None):
    if config_file_dir is None:
       config_file_dir = data_dir + '/config'
    print(data_dir)
    print(config_file_dir)
    print(json_schema)

validate_config('data')
```

**output**

```
data
data/config
None
```